# How do you efficiently work with the dimensions of tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, multidimensional-array, tensor

I'm trying to code a custom loss function for my machine learning model. Specifically, I'm trying to reduce false positives. This is my first attempt:

```py
def sens_spec(y_true, y_pred, sens_weight, spec_weight):
    FN = tf.math.maximum(0, y_pred[:][0]-y_true[:][0])
    FP = tf.math.maximum(0, y_pred[:][1]-y_true[:][1])
    TN = tf.math.minimum(y_pred[:][0],y_true[:][0])
    TP = tf.math.minimum(y_pred[:][1],y_true[:][1])

    FN = tf.math.reduce_sum(FN)
    FP = tf.math.reduce_sum(FP)
    TN = tf.math.reduce_sum(TN)
    TP = tf.math.reduce_sum(TP)
    
    sensitivity = TP / (TP + FN + K.epsilon())
    specificity = TN / (TN + FP + K.epsilon())
    
    return tf.math.subtract(1.0, (sens_weight*sensitivity, spec_weight*specificity))
    
    
def custom_loss(sens_weight, spec_weight):    
    def spec_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return sens_spec(y_true, y_pred, sens_weight, spec_weight)
    return spec_loss
```

So, for example, let's say this were our inputs:

```py
y_true = [[0, 1], [1, 0]] # ["positive", "negative"]
y_pred = [[0, 1], [0, 1]] # ["positive", "positive"]
sens_weight = 0.1
spec_weight = 0.9
```

The outcome then would be:

```py
FN == 0 # 0 False Negatives
FP == 1 # 1 False Positive
TN == 0 # 0 True Negatives
TP == 1 # 1 True Positive

sensitivity == 1
specificity == 0

loss == 0.9
```

It does work, but it is very slow. I suspect this is because of the inefficient slicing. The model outputs "negative" as [1, 0] and "positive" as [0, 1]. The shapes of y_true and y_pred therefore are (batchsize, 2) and I have to access the last dimension for my loss function.

**How do I efficiently access and apply math to the last dimension of a tensor?**

Comment: Can you please expand on your question and add an example `y_true` and `y_pred` with the desired outcome?

Comment: @gobrewers14 done. hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler if your labels and predictions were one element instead of two. If you are doing binary classification, the second column can be deduced from the first (or vice versa), making indexing unnecessary (and possibly speeding up your calculation).

```py
import tensorflow as tf


y_true = tf.constant([[0], [1]], tf.float32)
y_pred = tf.constant([[0], [0]], tf.float32)

sens_w = tf.constant(0.1)
spec_w = tf.constant(0.9)

FN = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(0, y_pred - y_true))
FP = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(0, y_true - y_pred))
TN = tf.reduce_sum(tf.minimum(y_pred, y_pred)
TP = tf.reduce_sum(tf.minimum(1-y_pred, 1-y_true))

sens = TP / (TP + FN + 1e-10)
spec = TN / (TN + FP + 1e-10)

tf.subtract(1.0, (sens_w * sens, spec_w * spec))
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.9, 1. ], dtype=float32)>
```